# Importing android application into Blackberry OS 10

Tags: android, performance, blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-webworks

I am trying to import an Android native app into the BB OS 10 but while configuring the Simulator it's not detecting it; I searched Google but was not able to find the solution.

Please let me know how to add the simulator to Eclipse and also, I run the VMWare Player but while playing I am getting

> Error recovering the memory

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have a stroll round the official BlackBerry Android micro-site - repackaging information is included there.

http://developer.blackberry.com/android/

You can deploy to a Simulator, though to be honest, it is easier to deploy to a phone (if you have one).

I have not had a memory problem running a Simulator.  Be aware that you start up your VM Player, and then open the Simulator VM within that.  This you should be able to do independently of anything else you are working on (like Eclipse).

I suspect the android forum will help with other questions you might have:
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Android-Runtime-Development/bd-p/adt